# 'Lost' cPanel files while using 'move' on file manager

Tags: cpanel, file-manager

I was moving some crucial files outside of the public_html directory to enhance security using the 'move file' feature on cPanels file manager.

I made a typo while typing in the destination for the files... Now the files have gone, they're not in the typo directory or the original. Surely the file manager doesn't delete the file if it can't find a directory to put it in?

I've enabled hidden files and looked in almost every directory, any clue as to wear they could have gone? Or how to undo that action?

Answer (score 0):

They appeared in a sub-directory of the original location as I forgot to add a "/" at the start, even though cpanel appears to have already done it for you.

Been looking in directory's for half an hour, post this question. A second later.. found!